# How do I get the video to play in my Video Selection Controller

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

I wrote a video selection controller so a user can select a video he wants to upload to firebase. Right now the problem I am having is that I can select the video but I cannot play it in the main view. It should work a little like the image/video selector in Instagram where if it's a video it automatically plays it. I don't need images at all, I only need videos to be uploaded.

What I see right now when select the video is a still of the first frame:

[image: Video Selection Screen]

I would be very greatful if someone could help me by telling me where I need to add what to making this video play automatically, or even with a play button in the middle of the screen.

My code right now to show the selection is as follow:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Photos

private let reuseIdentifier = "SelectVideoCell"
private let headerIdentifier = "SelectVideoHeader"

class SelectVideoController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

// MARK: - Properties

var images = [UIImage]()
var assets = [PHAsset]()
var selectedImage: UIImage?
var header: SelectVideoHeader?

// MARK: - Init

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureUI()
    fetchVideos()

    //Register cell classes
    collectionView.register(SelectVideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.register(SelectVideoHeader.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier)

    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 227/255, green: 227/255, blue: 227/255, alpha: 1)
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewFlowLayout

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    let width = view.frame.width

    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (view.frame.width - 3) / 4
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectVideoHeader

    self.header = header

    if let selectedImage = self.selectedImage {

        // Index selected image
        if let index = self.images.index(of: selectedImage) {

        // Asset associated with Selected Image
        let selectedAsset = self.assets[index]

        let videoManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)



        // Request Image
        videoManager.requestImage(for: selectedAsset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .default, options: nil) { (image, info) in

            header.videoSelectView.image = image

            }
        }
    }

    return header
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SelectVideoCell

    cell.videoSelectView.image = images[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.selectedImage = images[indexPath.row]
    self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc func handleNext() {
    let uploadController = UploadVideoController()
    uploadController.selectedImage = header?.videoSelectView.image
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: uploadController)
    present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func configureUI() {

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = (UIImage())
    //navigationItem.title = "Videos"

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleNext))
}

func getAssetFetchOptions() -> PHFetchOptions {

    let options = PHFetchOptions()

    // Fetch Limit
    options.fetchLimit = 30

    // Sort Videos by Date
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)

    // Set Sort Descriptor for Options
    options.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Return Options
    return options

}

func fetchVideos() {

    let allVideos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: getAssetFetchOptions())

    print("Function running")

    // Fetch Videos on Background Thread
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        // Enumerate Objects
        allVideos.enumerateObjects({ (asset, count, stop) in

            print("Count is \(count)")

            let videoManager = PHImageManager.default()
            let targetSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.isSynchronous = true

            // Request Video representation for specific Asset
            videoManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, info) in

                if let image = image {

                    // Append image to data source
                    self.images.append(image)

                    // Append asset to data source
                    self.assets.append(asset)

                    // Set selected Image
                    if self.selectedImage == nil {
                        self.selectedImage = image
                    }

                    // Reload collectionView with images once counr has completed
                    if count == allVideos.count - 1 {

                        // Reload collectionView on main thread
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play video by create instances of `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer`. Add following code in your selection view controller or create one new view controller and present by passing video url in that.

Add following code to play video.

```
import AVFoundation

var avPlayerLayer                               : AVPlayerLayer?
var avPlayer                                    : AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // You need to pass your url here.
    self.avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)

    self.avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.avPlayer!)
    self.avPlayerLayer!.frame = self.view!.bounds

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.avPlayerLayer!)

    self.avPlayer!.play()
}
```

This code will play your video immediately after your selection. You need required to pass url in `avPlayer`.

I hope this will help you.